Where can I download a driver for an Epson WF-7830 printer/scanner/copier/fax which I can use with Ubuntu?
I need the driver software for an Epson printer/scanner/copier/fax, model no. WF-7830, which is compatible for use on Ubuntu. Is this available for download anywhere?
My Ubuntu version is 22.04.4 LTS

If you do a search on Epson WF-7830 ubuntu divers you get to this, and there are linux drivers, next time pls search before asking.

@amar I did search, and was unable to find a driver. This is why I am asking other people here where if they know where I can find one. Telling me to search does not answer that question.

https://www.epson.se/sv_SE/support/sc/epson-workforce-wf-7830dtwf/s/s1832

@amar Thanks, that appears to be the driver I need. Now I just need to do an IT degree so I that can understand the instructions for how to install it. It's like reading Chinese for me. I don't understand why this process can't be user friendly for the average person.
